# Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit live USB created with UNetbootin either not recognised or "Disk Error" on Dell D630 BIOS A17

Tags: installation, boot, 13.10, live-usb, unetbootin

I know, I know, this question has been asked so many times but I have searched and searched and tried and tried but I can't get it to work.

I'm running Windows XP on my Dell D630. I downloaded the 64 bit Ubuntu 13.10 iso from the download page and "burnt" it to a FAT32 formatted 2GB USB drive with UNetbootin. I set up my BIOS so that USB devices are first in the boot sequence and even pressed F12 at the splash screen to make absolutely sure it was trying to boot from the USB drive. I removed all other USB devices, even my wireless USB mouse, but I get the dreaded "Disk Error" message. I have followed all the answers to similar questions on setting up the BIOS correctly, so enabling USB devices in the POST menu, enabling USB emulation etc. I have read about the difference between USB-HDD and USB-ZIP but I can't find any option relating to this in the BIOS so if this is the issue then I'd like to know how else to fix it.

No worries, I tried again with another USB flash drive I had spare, this time 1GB, I did everything specified above except this time there is no disk error but instead the flash drive appears to be unrecognised. This is only my assumption: when I select USB device from the boot menu, the screen goes black with a blinking cursor ("_") for barely a second then the laptop boots as normal. I even tried removing the HDD but then I am informed that there are no bookable devices.

I can boot from a 32 bit Ubuntu 12.10 DVD if it's any help. The laptop is a Dell D630 with an Intel T7100 processor, DT781 P/N motherboard (Intel graphics version), 1GB memory in each slot (so 2GB overall) and BIOS version A17.

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make your usb bootable using [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3)

and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked beautifully and quickly, the install worked fine. Sorry for not trying Universal USB Installer before, but all the queries I read suggested UNetbootin was the best one to use.